# How to set up vscode's snippet so it can automatically trigger vscode's intellisense after auto completion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-snippets

I had set up a custom snippets in `javascript.json`:

```json
"Node regular import": {
    "prefix": "creq",
    "body": ["const ${2:module} = require('$1')"],
    "description": "Node regular import"
},
```

It works when I type `creq` then press <kbd>tab</kbd>:

[image]

However, I would like this snippet auto-completion also trigger vscode's Intellisense. For now, I need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to get what I want:

[image]

Is there any way I could configure vscode so I don't need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are in a string, the following setting works against you:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
}
```

Change "`strings`" to `true` and that will help.  You still won't get the suggestions automatically opening up without doing anything but the first tab, but at least now typing something, like your first letter will trigger the suggestions instead of having to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Changing setting "strings" to `true` still doesn't help (at least in my vscode, possibly other settings required?), still have to do `Ctrl` - `Space` to trigger suggestions manually.

Comment: That is what I said.  Instead of Ctrl-space type your first letter and the suggestions will pop up.  If you don't know the first letter, you could eliminate the 's  from your snippet, so "const module = require()" and type a '.